# Mongo DB and storing data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I'm currently taking a webdev class in college, and we are at a section where we have to use mongo to store user information. I have been able to set up register and login end points that creates the data in mongo atlas, for example the format is:

```
id: ObjectId('65ff33d3bfe134749850da45')
username: "admi"
email: "email@gmail.com"
password: "$2b$10$DstkYh8VBDqd/aOmfQNJT.iVPCbJJRm9YgFcXGiOKL3qQ3/wUuXIi"
taskCount: 0
coinCount: 0
soldItems: 0
```

And as of now, the user's information for the counts are stored in local storage. But I can not figure out how to update the database for the specific user.

I have a `/data` end point, but I can't figure out how to use cookies to track the person logged in to call it for that user and update their info.

I'll be grateful for any help.

here is the /data backend ive made

'''

```
app.post('/data', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { taskCount, coinCount, soldItems } = req.body;
    const userId = req.query.userid;

    const user = await userCollection.findOne({ _id: userId });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
    }

    await userCollection.updateOne(
      { _id: userId },
      { $set: { taskCount, coinCount, soldItems } }
    );

    res.json({ taskCount, coinCount, soldItems, username: user.username, userid: user._id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error occurred while updating data:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
});
```

'''

i just cant get my front end to actually call it and send data.

Comment: Hi Jacob  Stack Overflow doesn't have dms unfortunately, so I edited out that line, but it's *always* helpful to share the latest code you've written to solve the problem :)

Comment: hey holo ad added my backend end point any advice on how to call it so it updates

Comment: Nice work! I'm not familiar with using mongo myself, but that should help the next mongo expert who stops by.

Comment: Passwords should never be stored as clear text in any database. Instead, you should store a hash value of the password.

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to reduce the number of trips to the database and reduce the likelihood of problems with competitive access, it is better to use the **findOneAndUpdate** method.
2. Your variable userId is of **String** type, but MongoDB stores the _id field in the **ObjectId** type, so before you use that field for selecting, you need to convert the userId variable to ObjectId type.
   Like this:

```
import { ObjectId } from 'bson';

const userId = new ObjectId(req.query.userid);
```